# How to reuse index space that was not created

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

My database is 34Gb in size and I created a clustered index which I believe was not successfully created due to some error and I can't find the index anywhere. During running of creation of Index, i was monitoring the hard disk size and it was decreasing while the creation of index is running. It took 10 gb space. Now, after the error in creation of index, the 10 gb space did not return. How can I get back this 10 gb of space? Thank you!!

Comment: In short, [DBCC SHRINKFILE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The free space is available within the file(s) although not available at the file system level for use by other applications. Although you could use `DBCC SHRINKFILE` as @DenisRubashkin suggested to release the space back to the OS, be aware that the file(s) will only grow again the next time you create the clustered index.